# how to use Go newRequest method

Tags: go

So, I've just started with Go and I'm trying to learn `HTTP` package. I found this program on the internet

```
headers := make(map[string]string)
headers["authorization"] = "1432536546" //the auhorization string

url :=    "anUrl\"

req, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", url, headers)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

But it is wrong, as it appears you can't use maps like this as they don't implement the `io.Reader` interface:

```
  cannot use headers (type map[string]string) as type io.Reader in argument to http.NewRequest:
  map[string]string does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)
```

This is one of the first code snippets I tried, I actually got it from what I thought to be a reliable source, and obviously it doesn't compile. Go looks pretty interesting, but it  has pretty much zero tutorials and useful documentation... Please help me, what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter is [Body](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=17718:17790#L536), which is used in POST requests. It is not for headers.
To add headers,

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", url, nil)
if err != nil{
    panic(err);
}

req.Header.Add("Authorization","1432536546") //string, string
```

The Go documentation does provide several examples. This one is the first example in the `Overview` section.

Comment: Thanks, this works, even if we probably should not read the sorce code of a programming language to use it.   Also, two more questions: so, how does this work? When is the request actually sent, if I modify it after the newRequest call?

Comment: And also: there is no way to add a whole map at once? This is just syntax, but it would be nice

Comment: @Micoloth you don't need to read the source, you can try to read the documentation... And no you can't add the whole map but you can do something like `for k, v := yourMap { req.Headers.Add(k, v) }`

Comment: @Micoloth http://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/http/ look at the 3rd example in the overview.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct, you can't use the [`NewRequest`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest) method from the `net/http` package in that way.

Moreover, it doesn't make a lot of sense as the third parameter of the `NewRequest` function is supposed to be the body payload of the request, not the headers.

```
func NewRequest(method, urlStr string, body io.Reader) (*Request, error)
```

Assuming the library is not incorrect, My assumption is that the `http` package here is not the `net/http` package, rather some sort of other HTTP client that is imported as `http`. In fact, if you import

```
import (
  "github.com/foobar/someclient/http"
)
```

it will also be referenced as `http`. You should check the import of the file.

FYI, the correct way to add headers is:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "/path/to/something", nil)
if err != nil {
    // do something
}
req.Header.Add("authorization", "1432536546")
```